# Windows 10 not saving PATH added variables after shutdown/restart

Tags: windows, windows-10, path

I added some paths to Windows environment variables in PATH, but everytime I restart/shutdown my PC it deletes these variables from Windows (My custom paths). I have to add them again. Why is this happening?

For David, I saw the "duplicate" answer but I think he didn't read title. It is still ignoring my path variables even after restart or shutdown. If I apply any of noth, it deletes it.

The question it's different because in my case, it's for restart/shutdown.
Duplicate answer is not valid in my question.

Comment: How exactly did you add them?

Comment: Windows Advanced System Properties -> Environment Variables -> PATH -> New -> "My\Path\Folder" -> Save -> Apply -> OK.

Comment: I'm not going to do cmd -> set path %PATH%;... I know that will work only in my current context

Comment: @DavidPostill Your duplicate flag is not valid. Please read my title. The issue continues after restart or shutdown. It applies to both. Your "duplicate" link is even a problem in my question.

Comment: Read the answer again. You need to reboot first before shutting down and restarting.

Comment: What part of "after restart OR shutdown" is not clear. By that I mean I tried:
* Create path -> Shutdown
* Create path -> Restart

That's the reason I put in the title shutdown/restart.

Comment: <sigh>The duplicate say "you need to actually **reboot** your machine via Windows -> Power -> Reboot after changing the setting **and not shut it down first.**". That is **not** what it says you have done in your question.

Comment: "Doing a proper reboot **skips the hibernation step** and lets the system **boot from scratch**," A reboot first is **not the same** as a "a shutdown and restart"

Comment: What part of -> "I tried restart first" and then "shutdown" and NONE of them works? lol
Let me explain in words you could understand: What you tell me to do, I did it, that's the reason i put a freakin slash '/' to mention that in any of both ways it don't saves it lol

As I said, the solution from your "duplicate" is a problem too. If you can't help, please don't keep commenting.

Comment: OK. Your question is reopened. Good luck.